# What is the SQL query to show another date format?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, type-conversion, format

I have two MySQL database tabels (named 'accounts' and 'events') with some columns like events.date. This column has a 'date' format. It shows the date as i.e. '2020-02-17'. Now I want to show some data from this combined tables with a query and I want to convert the date formate to DD-MM-YYYY instead of YYYY-MM-DD. I've tried some things but I got errors.

Queries I've tried:

```
SELECT events.id, convert(varchar, events.date, 105), events.starttime, events.endtime, events.reason, events.created, events.employee, events.employee_id, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(accounts.location, '1', 'London'), '2', 'Birmingham'), '3', 'Rochdale') location, events.minutes, ROUND((minutes/60), 2) as hours FROM events JOIN accounts ON events.employee_id = accounts.id ORDER BY date 

SELECT events.id, convert(date(4), events.date, 20), events.starttime, events.endtime, events.reason, events.created, events.employee, events.employee_id, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(accounts.location, '1', 'London'), '2', 'Birmingham'), '3', 'Rochdale') location, events.minutes, ROUND((minutes/60), 2) as hours FROM events JOIN accounts ON events.employee_id = accounts.id ORDER BY date
```

This query works well but shows me the wrong date format:

```
SELECT events.id, events.date, events.starttime, events.endtime, events.reason, events.created, events.employee, events.employee_id, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(accounts.location, '1', 'London'), '2', 'Birmingham'), '3', 'Rochdale') location, events.minutes, ROUND((minutes/60), 2) as hours FROM events JOIN accounts ON events.employee_id = accounts.id ORDER BY date
```

Can you please help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try  using TO_CHAR(datetime, format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp):

```sql
SELECT 
    events.id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(events.date, '%d-%m-%Y'), 
    events.starttime, 
    events.endtime, 
    events.reason, 
    events.created, 
    events.employee, 
    events.employee_id, 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(accounts.location, '1', 'London'), '2', 'Birmingham'), '3', 'Rochdale') location, 
    events.minutes,
    ROUND((minutes/60), 2) as hours
FROM events 
JOIN accounts ON events.employee_id = accounts.id 
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score -1):

use FORMAT function

To get DD-MM-YYYY use

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'dd-MM-yyyy ')
```

read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh213505(v=sql.110)

Comment: MySQL is an open source RDBMS, whereas SQL Server is a Microsoft product. The issue is related to MySQL, the link you have provided is of SQL Server. Also the link is of SQL Server 2012.